# Beginner Actionscript reference

Tags: flash, actionscript

My eight years old son asks to "teach him programming in Flash". Can somebody refer on good Actionscript learning resource online? The Flash version we have is "Flash MX".

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your son probably doesn't want to learn AS right away. He wants to be able to create fancy animation. I'd suggest teach him how to make Flash movies using timelines etc. Once he is able to grasp some of it, you can take up AS.

Comment: He already made some basic animation of moving shapes and color changes. Somebody told him that he may write an orders which will cause objects in Flash to move.

Comment: Amazing - your son will be a flash god by the time he reaches 20 years old :)

Comment: Hardly, in most cases kid do not persistent in their occupation, but hopefully he will widen his ken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see if this fits your bill:

http://www.scribd.com/doc/9409007/ADOBE-FLASH-ACTIONSCRIPT-BOOK

Answer (score 0):

[www.flashkit.com](http://www.flashkit.com)
[www.karupa.com](http://www.kirupa.com)

Comment: Thank you. Second one looks especially useful.

Answer (score 0):

You should also check out some stuff from top AS developers ([Brimelow](http://theflashblog.com), [Skinner](http://www.gskinner.com/blog/), [Moock](http://www.moock.org/)), although, nowadays much of the material will be focused on AS3 (Flash 9/10).

You might also want to upgrade to Flash MX2004, since that is when AS2 was introduced.  It's a much nicer version of the language to code in, and if the jump to AS3 is ever made,it won't be as tough as coming form AS1.

As far as books covering ActionScript go, check out Essential Actionscript by Colin Moock.  It'll cover pretty much everything you'll need.