# The Flash action Scripting For Beginners

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Beginner Actionscript reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832880/beginner-actionscript-reference)

Hi everyone, could you please help me, how can I learn ActionScript 3.0?

I know Flash very well, but I don't know ActionScript.

Comment: Try any of these http://stackoverflow.com/q/1510974/78782 http://stackoverflow.com/q/832880/78782

Comment: To be quite honest, none of those really have any detailed answers.

Comment: I recommend reading the "ActionScript 3.0 Bible" by Roger Braunstein.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you start off with the basics.

Here is an excellent link:

http://www.kirupa.com/developer/flash/index.htm#ActionScript_Basics

With that, you need to understand datatypes and how they work. Flash is a strongly-typed language, so you need to keep track of datatypes at all times.

This is the reference for the current (Flash Player 10) build of Actionscript 3.0 (compatible with Adobe Flash CS4 and up):

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/index.html

I'd suggest you start off the the `flash.display` section. That contains the classes beginners are most familiar with, those of course being `flash.display.MovieClip` and `flash.display.Sprite`. Here's a link to that package:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/package-detail.html

Primarily, you need to have a extensive knowledge of the following in Flash to be successful:

- MovieClips
- Sprites
- Arrays
- ints
- Numbers
- Strings

With a good knowledge of those datatypes, you should be well on your way. I guess a good question here would be "**how familiar are you with programming logic?**". Actionscript 3 is a direct descendant of the ECMAScript spec, ergo, a sibling to Javascript. They each have their own special quirks, but Actionscript 3 and Javascript are quite similar. I've found when learning them in conjunction, comprehension comes much quicker than learning them separately.

Failing these online resources, [*Essential Actionscript 3.0*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596526946) by Colin Moock is a must in my opinion. It's a wonderful reference with well-detailed examples that will get you off the timeline (presuming you were on it to begin with) and into Object-Oriented Programming.

Google Books has a free preview of that book here:

http://books.google.ca/books?id=gUHX2fcLKxYC&printsec=frontcover&dq=essential+actionscript+3.0&hl=en&ei=BkVGTcPYPIP4sAOOwMSgCg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false

Finally, just use Google for any quick snippets or questions you're looking for. I've found googling "(your problem here) as3" can have sufficient results for smaller, more popular issues. Good luck!

-Matt

Comment: Agree. kirupa is a great site for ActionScripters.

Answer (score 0):

Begin with reading tutorials online (of course you have to install Adobe Flash CS4/CS5 first). CS4 is a good start, as its controls are simpler. Here is a site I recommend:

http://www.actionscript.org/resources/categories/Tutorials/Flash/Beginner/

Comment: Most of those (optimistically) look to be intermediate level or higher.

Comment: the link is marked for beginner level, though.

Answer (score 0):

several examples : 
program generated smoke : http://wonderfl.net/c/pMG9 
sample menu leading to a video : http://wonderfl.net/c/5yZq 
an example of multiline textfield with lines added from the bottom instead of top : http://wonderfl.net/c/3cHE

Answer (score 0):

buy/read books.  learn the right way as well as starting your own developer's library that you can reference from years to come.  don't waste your time with sporadic, often misguided or incomplete online tutorials.

i recommend the following:

1. Appitizer - [ActionScript 3.0 for Adobe Flash Professional CS5 Classroom in a Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321704479)
2. Full Course Meal - [Essential ActionScript 3.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596526946)
3. Desert - [Adobe Flex 4: Training from the Source, Volume 1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321660501)
4. Icing - [Actionscript 3.0 Animation: Making Things Move](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590597915)
5. Updated Icing - [AdvancED ActionScript 3.0 Animation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430216085)

Comment: I am not That much Rich could you pls give me The Basic and Cost free book links.. pls Thanks a lot